# How to bypass android SSL Certificate check with Retrofit 2.0

Tags: java, android, ssl, ssl-certificate

i am a newbie in android programming. So any help would be greatly appreciated:
So i am working on a new project in which i am using Retrofit 2.0 beta 2(Rest Client). So what happened is that the site i use for my Web Service isn't verified and doesn't have a SSL Certificate. Can anyone help me to bypass the SSL Certificate check.

Answer (score 5):

This Question would be duplicated, the following response worked for me:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25992879/2096750

with the following implementation:

```
OkHttpClient client = getUnsafeOkHttpClient();
Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(myBaseUrl);
Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(client).build()
...
.
.
```