# How to trust self signed certificate on Android?

Tags: android, ssl, ssl-certificate, okhttp

I have generated self signed certificate for my server.
Then added it to Android with Settings -> Security -> Install.

When I'm trying to connect to my server from the application I'm getting error:

```
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

As I understand after I've added certificate to list of trusted ones it should work fine. Am I missing something?
The idea is to add certificate through Android system without modifying application code.

Btw I'm using `OkHttpClient` for network connection. Maybe I should enable something for `https` connection?

Comment: Possible duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25509296/trusting-all-certificates-with-okhttp

Comment: No it's not. I don't want to trust all certificates...

Comment: Did you import the CA certificate?

Comment: Yes as I said through Settings -> Security

Comment: Have a look here, it describes how to solve this exception: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#CommonProblems

Comment: Read this. It might be helpful. http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2012/03/unifying-key-store-access-in-ics.html

Comment: Do you have any update on this?

Answer (score 5):

It is important to Android that when you generate your self-signed certificate, you mark it as a Certificate Authority in order to empower it to certify certificates — even if only to sign itself and so certify that it is itself.

This is done in the `basicConstraints` extension, declaring `CA:TRUE` instead of the default `CA:FALSE`.  When you import a certificate so marked, Android will consider it a user-installed root certificate, and you should be able to see it under *Credential storage* → *Trusted credentials* → *USER*.

However, a certificate having this bit is a mighty power, and such certificates have been used by nefarious tools to spy on supposedly encrypted user communication in the past.  Accordingly, these days, Google Play Protect will want to have a word with the user when this kind of CA certificate is in force.

Comment: Do you know whether this has changed with Android 9? I know that I had this working in the past (after setting `CA:TRUE`) but with Android 9, I can't get it running anymore...

Comment: Indeed after changing CA:FALSE to CA:TRUE parameter, Android 11 has successfully imported the localhost.crt, but I still got an SecurityError: An SSL certificate error occurred when fetching script (while trying to register service worker)

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `src/debug/xml/`[`network_security_config.xml`](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#TrustingDebugCa).

It should look similar to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <debug-overrides>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="@raw/debug_cas"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </debug-overrides>
</network-security-config>
```

Where debug_cas is the custom certification authority you used to generate the certificate for your server. Beware that if you are using a local server accessing it by IP you must have a *subjectAltName* with that IP inside your server certificate, otherwise it will give you a `javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException`

Answer (score 0):

This example has two code paths
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70543735/1542667

Firstly adding to the network security config, and secondly adding in the okhttp client.