# Invalid SSL certificate in Android from a local server / host

Tags: android, ssl, nginx, localhost

I have a local server (Ubuntu, Nginx), which has a self-certified certificate installed. I have added the certificate to keychain access (on my Mac) as trusted, so when I load the page I get a valid certificate in chrome. Now I want to access the page via my phone (android), so I have installed the app virtual hosts and pointed the host to the server. When I access the page I get an SSL warning, is there any way to install the certificate on my device so that the cert is valid (needed for testing)?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to trust self signed certificate on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37281958/how-to-trust-self-signed-certificate-on-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android has some specific requirements when it comes to certificates, it's been some time since I had to import a certificate in an Android device, however make sure that its flagged as a root CA certificate.

The information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37281958/how-to-trust-self-signed-certificate-on-android) can help you with the details of it.

[This document](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2844832?hl=en) has the steps to import a certificate in the device.

Comment: Thank you the cert wasn't flagged, so doing that and reinstalling the cert rectified the problem.