# How to fix broken HTTPS on android when using a openssl self signed localhost certificate?

Tags: android, google-chrome, openssl, localhost, self-signed

I followed [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297139/how-do-you-sign-a-certificate-signing-request-with-your-certification-authority/21340898#21340898) on how to create my own CA and end entity certificates. My certificate authority (localhost) openssl config looks very similiar [to this](https://www.phildev.net/ssl/opensslconf.html). According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47212691/11141257) I've set

```
[ v3_ca ]
basicConstraints                = CA:TRUE
```

On my desktop devices there are no problems at all and https works fine.

Problems occur when I try to install the root certificate on my android device.

At first I installed the root certificate via the inbuilt '**install from storage**' option (*Settings / Security / Credential storage*). Https works now but I always get the [network may be monitored warning](https://www.howtogeek.com/198811/ask-htg-whats-the-deal-with-androids-persistent-network-may-be-monitored-warning/).

Following [this article](https://ivrodriguez.com/installing-self-signed-certificates-on-android/) I took the certificate hash, renamed the *rootca.pem* file to *{hashid}.0* file as suggested and moved it to */system/etc/security/cacerts/* using **ADB** on windows powershell (also set `chmod` and `chown`).

After rebooting my phone I can see that my authority certificate has been successfully added to android native trusted certificate storage. It's active by default.

Now I got rid of the networking monitor warning but ssl is not working anymore. Android chrome on remote debug throws:
[broken https certificate missing net::ERR_UNEXPECTED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnFfE.png) (firefox on android says `SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER`)

Is there a way to get around this/install it correctly? Did I forget something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested I'm sharing the solution:

**Here's what I did to solve this:**
  (1) flashing my sm-g900f with odin v3.12.4-4 and latest twrp 3.3.0-0-klte
(2) backup relevant data, wipe system/cache/... with twrp afterwards
(3) flash 16.0-nightly-klte addonsu-16.0-arm open_gapps-arm-9.0-nano-20190428
(4) install certificate via security settings options. Shown as 'user cert' but no warning message and ssl works now :)

Thanks to [JW09I4](https://forum.xda-developers.com/member.php?u=7189066) from XDA-Developers for helping me out and guiding me through the process of updating my phone.