# localhost self signed certificate trouble on telephone

Tags: android, ssl, iis-10

i have hosted a site on IIS and i connect regularly with google chrome on my pc. how can i access trough ip to that site with my telephone? 
there is any method to make android chrome to get certificates self signed for localhost?

Comment: what is a problem for you to access it by IP?

Comment: there is no problem in access by ip on telephone, i have problem that google chrome on my telephone see it as ''potentially dangerous'' because don't have the certificates for ''localhost'' that I created on my pc with openssl

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37281958/how-to-trust-self-signed-certificate-on-android

Comment: you still can open the potentially dangerous sites in chrome, or may just use HTTP instead of HTTPS