# SSL handshake exception retrofit android

Tags: android, ssl, retrofit, retrofit2, android-ion

I am getting unusual exception suddenly after base url got changed from http:// to https://. Every time I hit API with https:// I can see log flashing "HTTP FAILED: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found." this error.

I thought retrofit auto imports the certificate most times (as I have tried connecting https:// many times using retrofit. I didn't faced this issue earlier)

Comment: Follow that link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46969809/6740130

Answer (score 1):

Your server may use an auto-signed certificate for https.

If this is true, you can avoid the exception by disabling retrofit to check the certificate.

Please, read this:

[Disable SSL certificate check in retrofit library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37686625/disable-ssl-certificate-check-in-retrofit-library)

Comment: It is happening for Android 5.0 on retrofit version 2.9.0

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not on app side absolutely. Tell your supervisor that your HTTP clients can’t connect to fatally insecure HTTPS servers. You can say it's a limitation of computers and your only option is to update the server.

Once you’ve done that you can add a development-only debug mode. To do it, enable a cipher suite that your server supports. You can get the list from the Qualys tool.

Comment: Won't it be possible to use the ssl certificate in retrofit which they are using right now on server?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: Apparently they are using wildcard certificate as told by admin, is it something I can do from app side? Because whenever i use same API over postman, i can see the response.

Comment: @The90sArtist you can check if https has setup correctly or not here: https://www.digicert.com/help/

Comment: Eventually the postman gives the response it does not matter either it is http or https,it just gives the response. any way you can check the https has setup correctly as suggested by @maphongba008

Comment: Yes. Sure. Thank you.