# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Chain validation failed

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I have an Android app which was working fine in all devices but recently when I checked it in new **Android Samsung A6+** then get the exception i.e..

`HTTP FAILED: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Chain validation failed`

Getting this issue while calling web service using **Retrofit 2.4.0**. Here what am getting via catch block logs

```
Certificate has been revoked, reason: CESSATION_OF_OPERATION, revocation date: Wed Aug 15 01:42:14 GMT+05:30 2018, authority: CN=Starfield Validation Authority - G2, O="Starfield Technologies, LLC", L=Scottsdale, ST=Arizona, C=US, extension OIDs: []
```

Comment: It's working with "http" request and generating exception while using "https". It means the URL we are using to request web service should have SSL certificates. Thanks stack overflow!

Comment: So as the error says the certificate of that server is not valid anymore, Consider to avoid the certificate validation, following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37686625/disable-ssl-certificate-check-in-retrofit-library) or [this tutorial](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-trust-unsafe-ssl-certificates-self-signed-expired)

Comment: are you sure that the SLL certificate is still valid?

Comment: Thanks for your support ollaw and Black-8. Yes, I checked with the backend team and they address that the SSL Certification has been expired.

Answer (score 0):

Problem - javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Chain validation failed
solution - basically when you are using server api then this problem will occurs. some time this occurs, because of hosted data api subdomain ssl certificate expire. and one more thing this issue will be resolved from the server side.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.