# Retrofit API showing error , javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException:

Tags: android

When i run api and getting error `HTTP FAILED: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.` I have generated signed apk also but still showing error.

Comment: This is something related to your server end. What is the response code you are getting? Tell your backend person to install the correct certificates on the server.

Comment: I am not getting any response.

Comment: Please have a look to your internet connectivity

Comment: internet connectivity is prefect

Comment: Try disabling SSL certificate. Here go through this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37686625/disable-ssl-certificate-check-in-retrofit-library

Comment: I am using SSL on my site.

Comment: Hit the api in postman and check the response ...else check logs in studio for response.

Comment: @PrajwalWaingankar it's working in postman

Comment: Kindly share your api link here that you are hitting in postman.