# Why okhttp not send https request

Tags: java, okhttp

I'm making a simple request to [google.com](https://google.com) with `OkHttp3`

```
private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
public void run(String url, Callback callback) {

    okhttp3.Request request = new okhttp3.Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(callback);
}
```

And I see in fiddler this(red-okhttp request, green-browser)

[image]

Why OkHttp send `http://google.com:443`, why not `https://google.com`. Maybe he needs a certificate?

Comment: I found the right solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25509296/trusting-all-certificates-with-okhttp) you must ignores all SSL errors.