# getting OkHttp to trust all SSL certificates

Tags: android, ssl, okhttp

I found the following code on SO, to enable OkHttp to accept all SSL certificates from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25992879/492015)

```
private static OkHttpClient getUnsafeOkHttpClient() {
  try {
    // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
    final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {
        new X509TrustManager() {
          @Override
          public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
          }

          @Override
          public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
          }

          @Override
          public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[]{};
          }
        }
    };

    // Install the all-trusting trust manager
    final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
    // Create an ssl socket factory with our all-trusting manager
    final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

    OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    builder.sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, (X509TrustManager)trustAllCerts[0]);
    builder.hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
      @Override
      public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
        return true;
      }
    });

    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = builder.build();
    return okHttpClient;
  } catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
}
```

This is all of `MainActivity` which contains all the code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9)
        {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }



        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                OkHttpClient client =  getUnsafeOkHttpClient();

                    Request request = new Request.Builder()
                            .url("https://google.com")
                            .build();

                Response response = null;
                try {
                    response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                    Log.e("myTag", response.body().string());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    private static OkHttpClient getUnsafeOkHttpClient() {
        try {
            // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
            final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {
                    new X509TrustManager() {
                        @Override
                        public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                            return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[]{};
                        }
                    }
            };

            // Install the all-trusting trust manager
            final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
            // Create an ssl socket factory with our all-trusting manager
            final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

            OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
            builder.sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, (X509TrustManager)trustAllCerts[0]);
            builder.proxy(new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("104.35.8.91", 8888)));
            builder.hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                @Override
                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                    return true;
                }
            });

            OkHttpClient okHttpClient = builder.build();
            return okHttpClient;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to capture the traffic with Charles, but there is still SSL issues. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does OkHttp support accepting self-signed SSL certs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23103174/does-okhttp-support-accepting-self-signed-ssl-certs)

Comment: Can we see the stack trace?

Comment: 1) "there is still SSL issues." is not a very complete assessment of problems with needed details and 2) please provide an [mcve] if possible this is still a lot of code to read...

Comment: Please note that you will not allowed to ship an app containing this code on the Play Store, due to the security issues raised by blindly accepting all SSL certificates.