# Trust/whitelist a certificate in OkHttp (Trust anchor for certification path not found)

Tags: java, android, ssl, https, trustmanager

I'm experiencing a issue with android 4 devices that receive the following exception connecting to the server:

> java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for
>   certification path not found.
>          at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:410)
>          at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(SourceFile:319)
>          at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(SourceFile:283)
>          at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(SourceFile:168)
>          at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(SourceFile:257)
>          at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(SourceFile:135)
>          at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(SourceFile:114)
>          at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(SourceFile:42)
>          at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(SourceFile:147)
>          at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(SourceFile:121)
>          at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(SourceFile:93)
>          at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(SourceFile:147)
>          at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(SourceFile:121)
>          at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(SourceFile:93)
>          at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(SourceFile:147)
>          at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(SourceFile:126)
>          at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(SourceFile:147)
>          at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(SourceFile:121)
>          at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(SourceFile:254)
>          at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(SourceFile:92)

The server certificate is from Cloudflare, I checked it with several tools  like https://www.digicert.com/help/ and it seems ok.

But for some reason I don't understand it started to fail in Android 4 versions.

Tried the solution of trusting all certificates [[LINK]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25509296/trusting-all-certificates-with-okhttp) and it works but this obviously have security issues like exposing your app to a "man in the middle" attack

```
final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
        new X509TrustManager() {
            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
            }

            @Override
            public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[]{};
            }
        }
};
final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
okHttpBuilder.sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, (X509TrustManager) trustAllCerts[0]);
```

How can I implement a TrustManager with a default behaviour but whitelisting only the certificate of the server.

Thanks

Edit: Following the example at [OkHttp@CustomTrust](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/CustomTrust.java) (Thanks CommonsWare)

Used the command:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -servername www.serverdomain.com -connect www.serverdomain.com:443
```

At the certificate chain gave me two certificates with format:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
....
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Replaced the url and the certificates in the example with the obtained ones but it is still not working, any ideas?

Comment: https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/HTTPS#customizing-trusted-certificates

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare, please check the edit

Answer (score 0):

You need to store ur certificat into raw folder then :

```
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
InputStream instream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.gtux_cert);
Certificate ca;
try {
    ca = cf.generateCertificate(instream);
} finally {
    caInput.close();
}

KeyStore kStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
kStore.load(null, null);
kStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm(););
tmf.init(kStore);

SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

okHttpClient.setSslSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
```

More information here : [Security SSL](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl#java)