# How to do certificate chain validation on Android and iOS?

Tags: android, security, ssl-certificate, okhttp, owasp

Our app's security testing got a security issue related to certificate chain validation. It's CWE-296 https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/296.html

To my knowledge, adding a certificate pinning solves this problem but I'm not sure if there is a way to do certificate chain validation without pinning.

OWASP-MASVS also mentions about CWE-296 [here under references](https://github.com/OWASP/owasp-masvs/blob/66c2ff24957e994f2f48b08b831b2e69d782ad93/Document/0x10-V5-Network_communication_requirements.md)

Can someone please provide more knowledge on this? Possibly share some example app which does this.

We're using `Okhttp` for networking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on discussion with Jeroen Beckers and Sven Schleier from OWASP MSTG team, I learned that networking library (in our case `Okhttp`) should handle `certificate chain validation` by default. Unless the app has specific [custom implementation of TrustManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25509296/trusting-all-certificates-with-okhttp) where its trusting all certificate.

Sven mentioned that,

> once all the certificate checks are in place (chain validation, expiry
> of the certificate etc.), SSL Pinning can be implemented. So validation of the chain of trust for certificates always need to be there, SSL Pinning is then just another layer to make Man-in-the-middle attacks harder.

Our issue might be false positively flagged by pen-tester.

[Link of the discussion](https://owasp.slack.com/archives/C1M6ZVC6S/p1627568773054900) on OWASP Slack channel